# Mac: Dragging won't move folder -- instead creates alias

Tags: macos, user-interface, finder

I accidentally dragged an important folder into my Applications folder and now whenever I try to move it back, the system instead creates an alias and I can't move it to its previous location. i've never seen this before ... anyone have a suggestion/know whats up?

Comment: This would be more appropriate at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drag and hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> to force move.

It is **normal** to create an **alias** with a normal **drag**, if the file/folder is on **another disk** (that is also true if both disks are internal).

Maybe you accidentally pressed <kbd>⌘</kbd> (command), where you wanted an alias?